# Delete server header from response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx

Env :- Rails 3.2 , Ruby-2.1.1p76

```
Server: nginx/1.8.0 + Phusion Passenger 4.0.59
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 4.0.59
```

I want to remove these 2 headers from response. I know I can edit my nginx config and set `server_tokens` to `off` but is there any way I can handle this in codebase?

Comment: I don't think so, since those headers are added after the processing by Rails.  Also, Rails 3.2 is well past end of life and no doubt has many security holes.

Answer (score 0):

For that, There is a module named [headers more](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module). You need to compile it as dynamic/static module with Nginx.

Then you can add/remove/modify headers via following syntax in your server blocks:

Add/Edit Header:

```
more_set_headers "Server: Your_prefered_name";
```

Delete Header:

```
more_clear_headers "Server";
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this two options in nginx config-file:

```
passenger_show_version_in_header off;
server_tokens off;
```

This isn't remove server-strings from headers, but at least don't show versions:

```
Server: nginx + Phusion Passenger
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger
```